# Restoring Main Window on Electron JS

Tags: macos, electron

I created an app (done for OSX) that will send a message even when the main window is hidden, currently my main.js is like this:

```
const { app, shell, BrowserWindow, dialog } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const electron = require('electron')

// Enable live reload for all the files inside your project directory
require('electron-reload')(__dirname);

let win = null

function createWindow () {
   win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 420,
    height: 420,
    resizable: false,
    fullscreenable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  win.on('close', (event) => {
    if (app.quitting) {
      win = null
    } else {
      event.preventDefault()
      win.hide()
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')

  win.webContents.on('new-window', function(e, url) {
  // make sure local urls stay in electron perimeter
  if('file://' === url.substr(0, 'file://'.length)) {
    return;
  }

  // and open every other protocols on the browser      
  e.preventDefault();
  shell.openExternal(url);
  });

}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })



})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => { win.show() })

app.on('before-quit', () => app.quitting = true)
```

The idea is that when the user try to close the app it will just hide it. I'll need to add something that at certain hours of the day the app will launch the main window again.

Is there a way to make the main window be reopened or to run a code in the background so at certain time of the day the window will be unhidden?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Is there a way to make the main window be reopened or to run a code in the background so at certain time of the day the window will be unhidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure....this will reopen your minimized window

```
if (win) {
  if (win.isMinimized()) win.restore()
  win.focus()
}
```